# No basic authentication on windows using elasticsearch jetty plugin

Tags: elasticsearch, jetty

I installed Jetty plugin with the below command on windows8
    "bin/plugin -url      https://s3.amazonaws.com/www.emergi.net/elasticsearch/plugins/elasticsearch-jetty-1.0.0.zip  -install elasticsearch-jetty-1.0.0"

```
It installed successfully and add the realm.properties file in "elasticsearch-1.0.0/config" directory.
"realm.properties" file looks like 
user: pwd,readwrite
```

I added the below lines in "elasticsearch.yml" file

```
 http.type: com.sonian.elasticsearch.http.jetty.JettyHttpServerTransportModule
  sonian.elasticsearch.http.jetty:
   config: jetty.xml,jetty-hash-auth.xml,jetty-restrict-writes.xml
```

I restarted the elasticsearch with "elasticsearch.bat" command.

```
When I put -XPUT,-XPOST or -XDELETE command, it doesnt provide any authentication.
```

Can anyone tel me what i missed?
I followed the same procedure in linux.It works.

Thanks in advance.